# solve this problem of trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

It is given : 
$$\sin(A-B)/\sin B = \sin(A + Y)/\sin (Y)$$
We have to prove $$\cot B - \cot Y = \cot(A + Y) + \cot(A - B).$$

Please help me solving this.   I have tried to solve this by analyzing $$\cot B - \cot Y$$
From the given equation,we get $$\frac{\sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B}{\sin B} = \frac{\sin A \cos Y + \cos A \sin Y}{\sin Y} $$ or
$$\sin A \cot B - \cos A = \sin A \cot Y + \cos A$$ or
$$\sin A(\cot B - \cot Y) = 2 \cos A $$ or
$$\cot B - \cot Y = 2\cot A $$
but we have to prove $$\cot B - \cot Y = \cot(A + Y) + \cot(A - B).$$ 
I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: Hint: substitute $U = A - B$ and $V = -(A+Y)$, then invert both sides of the equation.  You'll see that you now have the same equation, but with $U, V$ instead of $B, Y$.

Comment: Can u plz elaborate?And of course which equation are u talking of?

Comment: U have just replaced the terms with a symbol.How can this solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you started with:
$$
{\sin(A−B)\over \sin B}={\sin(A+Y)\over\sin Y}
$$
Which led you to:
$$
\cot B−\cot Y=2\cot A
$$

Let $U = A - B$, which imples $B = A - U$.

Let $V = -(A+Y)$, which implies $Y = -(A+V)$.

Substitute these values into the first equation to get:
$$
{\sin U \over \sin (A - U)} = {\sin (-V) \over \sin(-(A+V))}
$$
Note that $\sin (-x) = - \sin (x)$, so the negative signs on the right half of the equation factor out, then cancel each other.  Now invert the equations to yield:

$$
{\sin (A - U) \over \sin U} = {\sin (A + V) \over \sin V}
$$

This equation is exactly the same as the first equation, but with U, V instead of B, Y.  Thus, using the same logic, you can conclude:

$$
\cot U - \cot V = 2 \cot A
$$
Substitute the definitions for $U$ and $V$:
$$
\cot U - \cot V = \cot (A - B) - \cot (-(A+Y)) = \cot (A - B) + \cot (A + Y).
$$

This is also equal to $2 \cot A$, so we can combine with the second equation above to yield:

$$
\cot B - \cot Y = \cot(A+Y) + \cot(A-B).
$$

Comment: U r really great but how can i know when the problem demands replacement of  a term with another like u did here to solve the problem?